# My regex to find illegal XML characters is very slow in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to identify if a string contains illegal XML characters.

To test, I create a 200K string of valid characters then add an invalid character to the end.

I then do a regex search with Python.

```
% time python3 temp.py
python3 temp.py  105.52s user 0.50s system 96% cpu 1:50.00 total
```

Should it take 105 seconds to run this 100,000 times?  Seems slow to me.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to speed it up? The only thing I need is to know if the string contains > 0 illegal characters, nothing more.

Some more information - if I change the regex to:

```
_illegal_xml_chars_RE = re.compile(u'[\x00]')
```

then the time is 8 seconds:

```
python3 tmp.py  8.17s user 0.11s system 80% cpu 10.282 total
```

To answer a comment, I also timed the script but exited immediately after creating the random message, which seems to take about 1/3rd of a second:

```
python3 tmp.py  0.36s user 0.03s system 92% cpu 0.422 total
```

Here's the code:

```
import re
from random import choice
from string import ascii_letters, digits

# make a 200KB string of valid characters
random_message = ''.join(choice(ascii_letters + digits) for i in range(200000))
# add an illegal character to the end
random_message += '\x00'
_illegal_xml_chars_RE = re.compile(u'[\x00-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1F\uD800-\uDFFF\uFFFE\uFFFF]')

for x in range(100000):
    result = _illegal_xml_chars_RE.search(random_message)
```

UPDATE:
I've decided in the end that the code here is probably pretty quick all things considered, as pointed out by @sabik and @Maxt8r . It's about 1,000 every 1.3 seconds. That's pretty good. Interestingly, I am using an existing approach in which I feed the data into an XML parser via Python and let it tell me if there are invalid characters. Both the XML parser and the regex approach are almost exactly the same speed.

*credit regex from:
https://lsimons.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/stripping-illegal-characters-out-of-xml-in-python/*

Comment: To be fair, it is scanning 20GB of data...

Comment: One possibility would be the `re2` library; it can be faster in some circumstances...

Comment: @sabik I added some further information - changing the regex brings it to 8 seconds, so the amount of data doesn't seem to be a factor.

Comment: Hmm, possibly there's some ASCII-only optimisation that kicks in with the simpler regex.

Comment: In any case, if you can install `re2` (which requires some C libraries), it has a good chance of being much faster here.

Comment: Its unclear what it is you're bench marking. Is this `random_message = ''.join(choice(ascii_letters + digits) for i in range(200000))` being timed ? And what is the purpose of adding a 0 at the end of random_message ?

Comment: And, is finding half of a surrogate pair considered an illegal character ? I mean doesn't it depend of if the source is utf16 ?

Comment: @Maxt8r I start by creating a 200K random string because the system I am building will be processing data of about that size.  I place the invalid character at the end of that string because I want the regex to have to search the entire 200KB before finding a result. I've updated the post with the timing of creating the random message only (about 1/3rd of a second).

Comment: @Maxt8r the zero at the end of the random message is an illegal XML character that the regex should find.

Comment: @sabik I tried to install re2 which immediately crashed due to some compilation issue so I'll skip that path .... I'm trying to find a solution that depends only on the base Python regex lib.

Comment: You realize that you're trying to run a test on a single 200000 * 100000 = 20,000,000,000 string. Thats 20 Gigabyttes Some hard drives take 60 seconds just to read and write that ! Anyway, you're initializing the regex engine 100,000 times, that by itself is problematic.

Comment: You don't have to go through all this trouble to test this

Comment: @Maxt8r can you show me where the 20GB string is please?  As far as I can tell it is 200,001 bytes.

Comment: 200 KB * 100,000 iterations = 20 GB

Comment: You're running character by character comparison using the regex `[this]`. Each time it operates on the string it finds and fails on the _last_ character. You repeat this process 100,000 times. That is 20,000,000,000 comparisons, or roughly 20 Gb string .

Comment: @jdaz yes it is running the test 100,000 times multiplied by 200KB, but annother commenter is saying it is a single 20GB string, which I cannot see.  100,000 regex searches of a 200KB string should not take long.

Comment: And since characfter classes are a _LIST_ of comparisons, you have about 7 seperate in-class comparisons. That brings the total up to 140GB string ! Every segment in a class carries an OR clause with it, if the first segment didn't match, it tries the next, i.e. _OR_You can add or decrease segments in the class and see the time change

Comment: Really, just take a fixed set of letters or words, like `AWbretsx` and duplicate it until you get 200,000 characters. Then make the regex find a letter(s) that are not there. Do that 100,000 times and you'll get the same results. It will test all the way to the end looking for those letters because none are there in the target.

Comment: Character classes are more complex than looking for literals. Classes represent a linear _list_ where each range is checked in succession for a match at _each_ character position.

Comment: Right, the default `re2` is Python2 only; sorry. Pity.

Comment: You have a 12 ratio between a trivial single char regex and a more complex one involving a number of single chars and character ranges, so the times are consistent. I am afraid that this can only be speeded up by using C code with the help of Cython, numba or a direct C interface. Looping in Python **is** slow.

Answer (score 1):

The answer starts with the difficulty in the problem, and ends with an optional optimization

---

I tested, just for kicks, how does Numpy fare with your problem (using the Integer version of your problem, and `numpy.isin`). As Numpy is as a consensus fast, and surprisingly is much slower (not even close), I think you need to consider your problem. `re` Apparently is very optimized for this kind of problem, likely with ranges handles somewhat like done in the bottom of this answer.

Your Illegal character set is 2079, your test above has a message of length 200000, you compare 100000 times, and the example is worst case (all letters in the message are valid, so all comparisons must be done). This is a number you can't escape (up-to some optimizations, that still scale with this size):

```
2079*200000*100000 = 41580000000000
```

This means you need to reconsider your design, because I don't think you will do better the `re` (or `re2`) for class comparison methods. A couple of options

1. Parallelize this algorithm, dividing the message into chunk
2. If you read this xml from somewhere such as the web, read in a stream comparing each incoming character against the illegal set

For posterity I also checked using a list comprehension using enumerate and looking for each ordinal in a set, but this is still much slower than `re`.

---

Of course, the fact we use integers in this answer give a good hint to another optimization - we can do comparisons much more easily for consecutive ranges, saving a lot of comparisons:

```
msg_array = np.array([ord(x) for x in random_message])

result = np.where((msg_array < 10) | (msg_array == 11) |
                  (msg_array == 12) |
                  ((msg_array >= 14) & (msg_array <= 31)) |
                  ((msg_array >= 55296) & (msg_array <= 57344)) |
                  (msg_array == 65534) |
                  (msg_array == 65535))[0]
```

is about twice as fast for me than `re`. Unfortunately the message is looped for each boolean condition, so the fastest way would just to write a loop in C and import it.

Comment: At least the 0xd800-0xdfff range could also be done as a bitmask; `msg_array & 0xd800 == 0xd800`; no idea if that's faster, slower or no difference.

Comment: BTW, typo: character 32 is valid in XML.

Comment: @sabik Thanks, fixed. The bitmask will save a comparison, so the benefit would be marginal would be my guess, but still, it would be an improvement.

Comment: I take that back, it's still two operations, so I'm not sure it will be faster, thinking about it again.

Comment: I've decided in the end that the code I have is probably pretty quick all things considered.  It's about 1,000 every 1.3 seconds.  That's pretty good.  Interestingly, I am using an existing approach in which I feed the data into an XML parser via Python and let it tell me if there are invalid characters. Both approaches are almost the same speed.

Comment: I like the idea of splitting up the string and running parallel tests, also the idea of evaluating the inbound stream.